# Turning a displacement animation into a rigged animation?

Tags: animation, displacement

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way i can convert this displacement animation into a rigged (with bones) animation in some way.

https://gyazo.com/9904508541eb7c9a092f7f1a8efe4aea

Can anyone help or is there just no way to do this?

[image]

Comment: There are always 33 ways to do something in Blender.  Please show your work as a Blender screen capture.  I am not sure why you might choose or not choose an armature.  There are so many options. Why not take a cylinder and an armature and weight painting and show a sample?  A bone moving back and forth on its axis will beform any weighted mesh.  If bones can animate facial features they can animate a cylinder.

Comment: Im a developer on Roblox, and i'm trying to import it into that platform, but roblox require's an armature to animate anything.